# Why won't my UITableView's selected cell display the checkmark accessory?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am working in Swift 3 and trying to get a table view cell to highlight green and show a check mark when tapped.

Currently, when I run the app I can select a cell and it will turn light gray, and once I select another it will then turn green but still fail to show the checkmark.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let mySelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    mySelectedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    mySelectedCell?.tintColor = UIColor.white
    mySelectedCell?.backgroundColor = green

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom UITableViewCell? Also are you verifying this `didSelectRowAt` function gets called?

Comment: Have you tried adding `cell.selectionStyle = .none` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None);
```

Answer (score -1):

cellForRow does not get the cell that's being displayed, it creates a cell for that index path. You need to keep a set of selected indexes then call update for that cell or the tableView and have code in cellForRow that adds the check mark accessory.